# VB.net to MySql Stored Procedure Error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm a total newb to stored procedures, so I may be missing something easy, but I researched the basics and I'm stuck trying to integrate it from vb.net code. I created a simple stored procedure (I think) that just runs a query of data for today's results:

---

-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetRuntestToday`()
BEGIN

Select * From runtest.runtest_records where
Test_Date=CURDATE()
order by test_date desc, Convert(test_time_stop,DECIMAL(5,2)) desc;

END
```

When I log on to the main MySql database and attempt to run it from the MySql prompt, it appears to work fine. I simply type `call runtest.GetRuntestToday();` and it returns 59 rows of data in command prompt text form.

I wrote a VB.net program to try to get that same data but I keep getting an error. The error exception details are:

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2146232009
  Message="ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GetRuntestToday' at line 1"
  Source="myodbc5.dll"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at MySqlHelper.mMain.DoMyStoredProcedure() in C:\vss\MySqlHelper\MySqlHelper\mMain.vb:line 2642
       at MySqlHelper.mMain.Main() in C:\vss\MySqlHelper\MySqlHelper\mMain.vb:line 29
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The code I am running is:

```
Public Sub DoMyStoredProcedure()

    Dim MyConString As String = "My String Details"
    Dim dbcRuntest As New OdbcConnection(MyConString)


    Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand
    Dim reader As OdbcDataReader

    cmd.CommandText = "GetRuntestToday"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = dbcRuntest

    dbcRuntest.Open()

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    dbcRuntest.Close()
End Sub
```

The error happens on the line:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

What am I missing? I don't see any syntax problems and the stored procedure works from the command prompt. I've played around a little with the DELIMITER stuff making it // instead of $$ but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: why are you using obdc instead the properly connector for .net from MySQL? You can call a procedure just using that. cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-stored.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try changing to a direct call (I haven't tested this:

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 cmd.CommandText = "CALL GetRuntestToday"
```

Also, a better way of writing your code:

```
Dim MyConString As String = "My String Details"
Using dbcRuntest As New OdbcConnection(MyConString)
  dbcRuntest.Open()
  Using cmd As New OdbcCommand("CALL GetRuntestToday", dbcRuntest)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Using reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
      'do someting with reader'
    End Using
  End Using 
End Using
```

The `Using` structure automatically closes the connection and disposes it (along with the other objects).

**Edited to use CALL instead of EXECUTE**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that code but got another exception on the code with the Using reader statement.

Unknown prepared statement handler (GetRuntestToday) given to EXECUTE"
  Source="myodbc5.dll"

Comment: @JasonShoulders, I'm sorry to hear that.  I might be grasping at straws, but is your ODBC driver pointing to the right database (I'm assuming `runtest`.)  You might also try putting `runtest.GetRuntestToday` in your code.  Just some suggestions because the VB code looks correct.

Comment: I added a snippit of code just to prove it his hitting the db right. It is. I get back 62 records when getting a dataset back running a query on the dbcRuntest connection.

I think I had already tried runtest.GetRuntestToday but I just tried it again and still no go :(

Could it have anything to do with permissions? My login id is root, so I would't think that would be it.

Comment: @JasonShoulders, Okay, one last shot.  Change `EXECUTE` to `CALL`.  If that doesn't work, go back to your original command string but add parentheses to the end:  `GetRuntestToday()`.

Comment: Eureka! I think that fixed it - adding the CALL. It didn't error and I can see the data in the reader. I'm not a big fan of having to iterate through each record in the reader, but that sounds like a different thing to research.

Do you want to put a separate comment with the "CALL" answer, or just mark the original response as the answer?

I copied that code directly from a post on this site. I wonder why they didn't need the CALL statement and I did. I'm using MySql - maybe that's the difference.

Comment: @JasonShoulders,  Awesome!.  I changed my answer to show CALL.  I'm guessing that ODBC still needs the same underlying syntax as the RDBMS it's connecting to.