# Call a stored procedure with parameter in c# and MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I can do a updating in my program and I try to do an update by call a created stored procedure from my database.

in this example I have to get the value of the checkbox selected in a gridview and update it

in the gridview one or more boxes can be checkbox

My `FirstSP`

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS FirstSP$$

CREATE PROCEDURE FirstSP(idUser char(4), oID INT (11))

DECLARE idUsern CHAR (4);
DECLARE IDn INT (11);

SET @idUsern = idUser;
SET @IDn = oID;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM doTable_', idUser, 
                ' WHERE idUser = ? AND ID = ?;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt USING @idUsern, @IDn;

set @query = CONCAT(' UPDATE doTable_', idUser,
                    ' SET xExists = 1 WHERE idUser IN (?) AND ID IN (?);');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @idUsern, @IDn;

END

DELIMITER ;
```

the stored procedure tested in the dabatase works but I can try for single user

but tested in c# I have error

I've tried with selected single or multiple checkboxes

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FirstSP' at line 1 

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In debug the return of parameters is

```
S110
16
S110
15
```

I searched on google for some good example but I found nothing interesting.

my code below

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (CheckBox)(row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow"));

        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            int oID = Convert.ToInt32((gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));

            if (oID > 0)
            {
                using (OdbcConnection con =
                    new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (OdbcCommand cmd =
                        new OdbcCommand())
                    {                                
                        cmd.CommandText = "FirstSP";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idUser", "S110");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("oID", oID.ToString());
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net to MySql Stored Procedure Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781793/vb-net-to-mysql-stored-procedure-error)

Comment: @GSerg I've tried the suggestion of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781793/vb-net-to-mysql-stored-procedure-error but i've error